# How to remove ants from seeds like falooda?

Tags: pest-control

Is there any way to remove tiny red ants from falooda seeds, or urad dal.
I have spread the seeds on a paper, but then also they are not going away. How do I get rid of them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure of the size of a falooda seed, but if the ants are larger then you should be able to shake them through a sieve (or fine colander) to separate them from the ants. Then you have a sieve full of ants, though, which is pretty icky.

Another option, if it's all right to get them wet, is to submerge them in water. I believe the ants will most likely float, and you can skim them off the surface of the water. It may not work 100% the first time, so you may have to then pour out the water and transfer the falooda seeds to another water-filled pot.

After the ants are removed, I recommend keeping your seeds in a sealed container.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  In the future, can you make multiple suggestions as multiple answers?  As it stands now, I don't know which suggestion op used.

Comment: I did that when I was new to Stack Exchange, and a moderator told me not to do multiple answers. That seems weird to me, but that's what they said (unless I seriously misread it!). I do prefer the approach of merging multiple answers if they are somewhat similar, and separating answers only when they are completely unrelated. But I'll see what the moderators think if I do that in the future.